# How to get element content by id from HTML object by JavaScript ( JQuery )

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery

i write the following code to access page "JQueryPage.aspx" and get data from it using jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $.get
    (
        "JQueryPage.aspx",
        function(data) {
            alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
          } 
    );

</script>
```

"JQueryPage.aspx" is just a page that contain DIV called 'resultsDIV' that contain the data that i want to return

the above code return data variable that contain "JQueryPage.aspx" html and i want to get DIV content from it .. 
i have 2 questions: 
1- how can i extract DIV content from data object 
2- is this way is th best to get that data ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

    $.get 
    ( 
        "JQueryPage.aspx", function(html) { 
            var page = $(html);
            var div = $('#div1', page);
        }  
    ); 

</script>
```

you can also look into the [`$.load`](http://api.jquery.com/load) function

Comment: thanks, that's what i want and i will get div content by make :
var div = $('#div1', page).html();

Answer (score 0):

Jsut wrap the data in a call to jquery and you can use it like you would normally:

```
$.get
    (
        "JQueryPage.aspx",
        function(data) {
            var dataDom = $(data);
            $(someSelector, dataDom).each(function(){
                alert($(this).html());
            });
          } 
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

1. If the html markup of `JQueryPage.aspx` is valid xml, you can use dom parser to get the required div.
2. It depends - if all you want is to add the retrieved html to the existing DOM using a call to `document.appendChild`, yes. But if you need to parse and read values from the retrieved data, no, this is not. Pass data as a JSON string or xml.